# dax calculate context doesnt seem to be working

Tags: dax

My 2012 Tabular Model is based on the diagram you see below.  The code for my AgreementRate measure is shown below too.  According to pages 130-131 in Marco's The Definitive Guide to DAX, Copyright 2015, Chapter Six, DAX Examples, the **calculate** you see in my query (shown below) should show my measure in the context of the current row's employee id.  But rather it shows the overall value on every row returned.  What am I doing wrong?

```
AgreementRate:=Calculate(Sum('Fact'[AnswerFlag]),'Fact'[PositiveNotOther]=1) / (Calculate(Sum('Fact'[AnswerFlag]),'Fact'[PositiveNotOther]=1) + Calculate(DistinctCount(Fact[FK_CaseId]),'Fact'[NegativeNotOther]=1))

evaluate addcolumns(
                filter(Fact,related('Questions'[IsOther]) = 0),
                "Name",
                related(Employees[Name]),
                "FormName",
                related(Forms[FormName]),
                "StudyName",
                related(Studys[StudyName]),
                "Question",
                related(Questions[QuestionText]),
                "Rate",
                fact[AgreementRate],
                "agree1",
                calculate (fact[AgreementRate],
                           allselected(),-------------------------------------------original filters
                           --values(Employees[Name])--------------------------------supposed to be current context
                           values (fact[fk_empid])----------------------------------supposed to be current context

                          )
               )
```

[star diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkLP2.png)

Comment: I tried adding the dax calculate as a measure rather than coding it inline as shown in the query.  And that worked.  So my question now is "is this a bug?" or "in general are inline calculates not as dynamic as one might think?"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to achieve this - remove all filters except the one from Employees[Name] or fact[fk_empid].
to do this
you need to wrap a CALCULATETABLE() around your VALUES()-functions so it is calculated in the context of the current row and keep the values of the current row for Employees[Name] or fact[fk_empid] and remove all other filters using ALLSELECTED()

Comment: close but not really.  I want the measure for the current row employee (current row context) within the context of the other filters already in play.  I think that is what you are asking.

Comment: well, actually the problem seems to be that you do not have any aggregations at all. Have you tried using SUMMARIZE, SUMMARIZECOLUMNS or GROUPBY to create an aggregated level over Epmloyees[Name], Forms[FormName] and Study[StudyName]?

Comment: Thx Gerhard.  I have but the question here is why adding the same code in a measure produces such an aggregate at the employee level when selected as a column but inline it doesn't.

Comment: by using CALCULATE(..., ALLSELECTED(), ...) you change the context of the calculation. ALLSELECTED() removes all previous filters that come from the context of the current row

Comment: thx Gerhard.  The definition I'm seeing on pg 125 of the definitive guide by russo says "ALLSELECTED returns only the values that are visible in the original filter context, that is, the one of the pivot table.".   Also, if I remove it and just leave VALUES, I still get the wrong answer.  But if I make a new measure with the exact same expression you see in the calculate, and select it as an additional column, it comes out right.  Thus the question, why does a measure come out right but the exact same expression (used to make that measure) coded inline wrong?

Comment: Hi Gerhard.  I'm just noticing...that section of the book uses only expressions for measures as examples, no examples that use evaluate.

Comment: did you also check Marocs blog on ALLSELECTED? http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-allselected/

Comment: actually, ALLSELECTED removes the last filter context. 
can you verify this:
if your expression is evaluated in the row-context, it removes the filter from the current row, still keeping the other filters  (e.g. Question[IsOther] = 0)

if the expression is evaluated as measure, it removes the last filter (which is Question[IsOther] = 0)

Comment: That article is a head breaker!  I will gladly try what u ask but need clarification first.  When u say "if your expression is evaluated in the row context" do u mean in an evaluate?  And just for clarification does the values clause count as a filter also?

Comment: sure, VALUES used as second (or later) parameter of CALCULATE is a filter for the expression (=first parameter) that is evaluated. However, if multiple filters are applied, the result will be the intersection of all filters - e.g. for ALLSELECTED and VALUES